# Symfony 2 lowercase-uppercase the "i" letter locale bug

Tags: symfony

This is the error it gives me when i try to:

`http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/`

```
ErrorException: Warning: constant() [function.constant]: Couldn't find constant Monolog\Logger::iNFO in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/MonologBundle/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php line 102
```

I know that the Turkish locale causes this error. But i can not use any other locale than Turkish, i must solve this.

In Turkish language look at these letters:

Lowercase "i" turns to "İ" in uppercase.

Lowercase "ı" turns to "I" in uppercase.

I think this convention is where it conflicts with English language and causes this kind of errors.

But how i can i fix this?

Reported:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3198

Comment: Are you are using symfony Standard Edition? Which Version?

What changes did you make? Only change default_locale? Plese provide some more info, as this may be a major bug in translator component.

Comment: Symfony Standard Edition 2.0.9. Zero change. Just extracted and tried to start. Also Code Igniter have this bug too. Yes very major, if you can't fix it you can not use the frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug caused [by the following piece of code in MonologBundle](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/MonologBundle/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php#L102):

```
 constant('Monolog\Logger::'.strtoupper($handler['level']));
```

Problem with Turkish locale is known on php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php#97667

Report a bug with steps how to reproduce it [on github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues).

Read [how to report bugs in the official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/contributing/code/bugs.html).